# Angular13 Multi filters on columns return []

Tags: angular

I try to use filter for on multi columns  but When typing letter in on field , my table is empty and  no error on console.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [ngModel]="globalFilter" (ngModelChange)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter"/>
</mat-form-field>


<mat-paginator *ngIf="dataSource" #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 50]">
</mat-paginator>
<table  mat-table  *ngIf="dataSource" [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by name">Name
      <div>
      <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="nameFilter" placeholder="NameFilter"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
 this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((filterValue) => {
      this.filterValues['name'] = filterValue;
      console.log(this.filterValues);
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
    });
...
```

```js
constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient,private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) {
    this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((filterValue) => {
      this.filterValues['name'] = filterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
    });
    // Others 
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();

   }

 applyFilter(filter:any) {
    this.globalFilter = filter;
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

 
  customFilterPredicate() {
    const myFilterPredicate = (data: Domaine, filter: string): boolean => {
      var globalMatch = !this.globalFilter;

      if (this.globalFilter) {
        globalMatch = data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.globalFilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      }

      if (!globalMatch) {
        return false;
      }
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.name.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.name) !== -1 && // others columns
    }
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
  
filterValues: any = {name:'',...};
```

`{ "name": "a", "description": "", ... }`

I try to add  `.trim().toLowerCase();`
but same issue.
It seems to only work when this.dataSource.filter is empty.
i make console filter is JSON and data is object
Work only when this.datasources.filter is '', when i have Object return 0 element.
i try to follow this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-5jeaic?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts,app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html,app%2Ftable-filtering-example.css)

Comment: It's looks like work :( -the element that fullfilled all the conditions is showed, e.g. "global filter "e",  name "l" and position "2" show "Helium". BTW try to **refresh** the .html (F5) (perhafs the problem is that you wrote Observables that they are not unsubscribe

Comment: what is "Helium" ?

Comment: The element Helium, with atomic number 2 and symbol He (the only element that fullfilled all the conditions in the stackblitz). The stackblitz it's OK so, the only to not work is that you're not create the formGroup before subscribe

Comment: the stabliz is only an example that I try to reproduce. and whatever I enter no longer see any element even if the whole filter is empty, I am not from formGroup. I tried to move the subcribt in AfertInit same problem.

Comment: that's it I moved the dataSource customFilterPredicate affection just after its initialization, but I don't understand why it doesn't work who I recover my dataSource in oninit and I assign customFilterPredicate in AfertInitView it's supposed to be after

Comment: each time you use `dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(what-ever)` your dataSource has no filter or filterPredicate of sort. You create a **new** MatDatasource. it's the reason to asing the filter and filterPredicate **after**